# Enable directory browsing in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, app-config, directoryservices

Does anyone knows how to do directory browsing using WCF and app.config file.
I tried doing

```
<system.webServer><directoryBrowse enabled="true"/></system.webServer>
```

but it did not helped. I need to make one directory within my Server available for users to download their files and I am implementing self hosted WCF services. I can share the files using IIS but it would be good if I can do it from WCF alone.

Comment: those settings are for IIS only. WCF does not have that faclility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directory browsing is a feature in IIS.  IIS makes it available; when you use WCF self hosting, you don't have all of those options unfortunately.  But it's possible to make a folder in your self-hosted folder structure a virtual directory in IIS so that they can get it there instead, if a hybrid is an option.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to achieve that is to also self host [Katana](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com).